# How do I open a document at the maximum full screen size, instead of less than full screen?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I noticed when I open any document (psd/jpeg/etc.) it opens at around 70% of maximum view size, instead of 'full screen' (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>).

How do I open images at full screen by default?

I checked preferences, but couldn't find it..

*Yes, the document exceeds my screen resolution.*

Comment: Is this to save a keystroke or is there another reason for the question?

Comment: No, actually to save a keystroke. However, when editing (in my current situation) 500 photos, I've to press the key combo 500 times. Therefor looking for some automation. :)

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer The figure keeps fluctuating between 500 and 300. Anyway i have a script that opens a image with open as  for a different name/folder ( so you can not accidentally overwrite original),  runs action to prepare image. When you run the script again it saves the image, opens the next image in folder and runs action... this saves a TON of time when bound to hotkey. I can clean the script up if your willing to wait one or 2 days. anyway you can do similarish things with the builtin batch processor meanwhile. Yeah ive have done a thousand picktures cleanup sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a partial help:

1. Open a file, any file
2. Create a new action, let's call it Fit to Screen
3. Choose from the action fly out menu "Insert a Menu Item"
4. When the dialog window opens waiting for a menu item be selected, go to "View/Fit to Screen"
5. Stop recording the action

Now you can open multiple files, say a dozen at a time and apply the action to all open files:

1. After your files are all open, go to File/Automate/Batch
2. Make sure to select "Opened Files" instead of folder location
3. Make sure that your desired action "Fit to Screen" is selected in the actions list
4. Click OK

Now all open files will have the images fitted to screen as if you pressed "Cmnd-0 or Ctrl-0" in all of them.

Comment: Well this sure fits as a temporarily solution, thanks!